# Unzip zip files within a zip file in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

The situation is that a zip file contains multiple zip files inside of it, I would like to essentially unzip 2 layers within ADF. Nearly all videos/guides only have one zip file that needs to unzipped so I am not sure what to do.

When I unzip the outer zip file inside the folder contains a binary file that is not useful

Answer (score 0):

In ADF, currently it is not supported to unzip two level zip files at the same time. So, you have to use copy activity two times to unzip the child level zip files like below- using Binary dataset.

[image]

give the temporary folder for sink of 1st copy activity.

[image]

Then use Get Meta data activity to list the child items and give that to a  ForEach and inside ForEach use another copy activity.

[image]

For this source use dataset parameters and give `@item().name` and in sink binary dataset give `file_name.csv`.

[image]